# Advanced search and elastic search

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, advanced-search

Magento2 site was added elastic search, in Advanced search page: now I try to find a product (product name) by entering the first 3 letters - it does not work when I enter - "for", but it works when I enter "For",
how can I allow to search products case-insensitively, via the elastic search for search filed working all properly?

Comment: By default, it should be case insensitive already. Do you have any third-party search extensions installed? The reason I ask is because your catalog could have been indexed with a non-standard Elasticsearch analyzer. Normally, it would use 'standard', or for some modules, 'custom' with a 'lowercase' token filter.

Comment: yes, i have also Elasticsearch

Comment: No, Elasticsearch is the search engine. Do you have any third-party search modules installed, such as Amasty's search extension?

Comment: Perry, sorry but not, i dont have any search modules except engine and basic M2 module for search bar